# @Test failed when calling method has softassert fails

Tags: java, selenium, testng, assertions

Soft assert failed to continue testcase from parent class:

In below testing, the second method `AssertTesting.softassert()` is completed with failed soft assertion, but the run is stopped after the second method. I want to execute the third method `AssertTesting.softassert2()` from the parent class. Any other way I can use soft assert, so I can continue the execution

```
            package Assertion;

        import org.testng.annotations.Test;

        public class AssertTestingAll 
        {
            @Test
            public void callallAssert()
            {
                AssertTesting.Hardassert();
                AssertTesting.softassert();
                AssertTesting.softassert2();
            }

        }



    package Assertion;

    import org.junit.Assert;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    import org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert;

    public class AssertTesting 
    {
        static SoftAssert sa=new SoftAssert();


      public static void Hardassert() 
      {

    //    Assert.fail("Assertion fail");

          Assert.assertEquals("strings dont match:", "Test", "Test");

          {
          String [] name1= {"jeeva","balan","madhu"};

          String [] name2= {"jeeva","balan","madhu"};

          Assert.assertArrayEquals("name does not match", name1, name2);
          }


          Assert.assertFalse("numbers does not matches ", 2<2);

          Assert.assertSame("jeeva", "jeeva");



      }

      public static void softassert()
      {
          sa.assertEquals("strings dont match:", "Test1", "Test");

          {
          String [] name1= {"jeeva","balan","madhu"};

          String [] name2= {"jeeva","balan","madhu"};


          Assert.assertArrayEquals("name does not match", name1, name2);
          }
          System.out.println("execution continued");

          sa.assertFalse(2<2,"numbers does not matches ");

          sa.assertSame("jeeva", "jeeva1");
          sa.assertAll();

      }


      public static void softassert2()
      {
          sa.assertEquals("strings dont match:", "Test1", "Test");

          {
          String [] name1= {"jeeva","balan","madhu"};

          String [] name2= {"jeeva","balan","madhu"};


          Assert.assertArrayEquals("name does not match", name1, name2);
          }
          System.out.println("execution continued");

          sa.assertFalse(2<2,"numbers does not matches ");

          sa.assertSame("jeeva", "jeeva1");
          sa.assertAll();

      }

    }
```

Comment: you were expecting this: sa.assertFalse(2<2,"numbers does not matches ");

          sa.assertSame("jeeva", "jeeva1"); to succeed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods of `SoftAssert` like `assertEquals` or `assertFalse` only record if the condition is fine or not and they do not throw any exception that indicates test failure to `TestNG` runner. The actual check and exception throwing happens in `assertAll` method.

This explains why you get this error. `softassert` method runs `assertAll` which throws exception and the test stops its execution at that point.

If you want the test to continue you need to use the same `SoftAssert` instance for all tests and run `assertAll` at the very end of the whole test.

Comment: //If you want the test to continue you need to use the same SoftAssert instance for all tests and run assertAll at the very end of the whole test.// This worked, i have initiated softassert class in parent class and ended softassert all in parent class method. the execution continued in Parent class methods all method object and listed all errors and execution completed.

Answer (score 0):

One of the assertions in `softassert()`, so when you use `sa.assertAll();` at the end of the method an exception is being thrown. From the [docs](http://static.javadoc.io/org.testng/testng/6.8.8/org/testng/asserts/SoftAssert.html#assertAll())

> When an assertion fails, don't throw an exception but record the
>   failure. Calling assertAll() will cause an exception to be thrown if
>   at least one assertion failed.

If you want to fail the test if any assertion has failed call `assertAll();` at the end of the test.